# Can different Glassfish domains be owned by different unix users?

Tags: unix, users, glassfish

Is it possible to assign different unix users to each domain under

```
${GLASSFISH_HOME}/domains
```

?

I tried assigning different users (even though same belonging to common group) I found permission related errors (writing to other sub folders `${GLASSFISH_HOME}`)  while attempting to start domain.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you could do it with ACLs if you're running on Linux (setfacl/getfacl) but by far the easiest and less error-prone way is just to have 2 separate full glassfish installations and then setting up the domains on those 2 installations not to collide in terms of ports.